# No password prompt when using rsync remotely?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have a bash script that executes rsync transfers to a remote location, and every time I execute the script I get asked for a password.

Is there a way to avoid this?

This is the command I use: `rsync -av /source usr@ip:/destination`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `rsync` over SSH and use an SSH key without a passphrase.

`man rsync`:

```
-e, --rsh=COMMAND         specify the remote shell to use
```

`rsync -e ssh ...`

Comment: I used ```ssh-keygen``` and ```ssh-copy-id``` but this looks easier.

Comment: @Dominique This can only be done after SSH has been configured. It's not an alternative to what you did.